# Homework question: get probability from distribution / table

Tags: probability, self-study

> Josefina is the star athlete on her college soccer team. She especially loves to score goal(s), and she does this on a regular basis. Suppose, the random variable X = the number of goals Josefina will score tonight. The probability distribution of X is given.
>
> ```
> X       0       1       2       3
> P(X)    0.25    0.35    0.25    0.15
> ```
>
> The probability that Josefina will score fewer than 1 goals tonight is _____.

I'm definitely getting stuck at all of it. I need help figuring out how to get the answers I need. This is a homework question, but I need to know how to figure it out.

Comment: It is homework, what I'm wanting is the steps to how I get the answer.

Comment: Then please edit the question to 1) focus on the question itself without the extraneous details.  2) Tell us what you have tried, what your understanding of the question is, and where you are getting stuck.  3) Add the self-study tag.

Comment: This appears to meet our standards now.

Comment: Sorry, I was wondering how to figure out how many goals she will get?

Comment: Is it the question from before (that I put back in the text)?

Comment: yes, I don't just need an answer, I was hoping for step by step, because I'm not understanding when I read it.

Comment: @Misty, you can begin from the detection of distribution law which correspond to your table. Then re-write your question in probability terms. like this, $P(X<1)=C_n^m p^m q^{n-m}$

Comment: @Nick It's difficult to see where any such formula would come from.  The probabilities are given by the table in the question, not by a formula.

Comment: Either the answer to this is really, really simple or there is some detail which you are not showing us. Or I have misunderstood.

Comment: @mdewey It's just a simple homework problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hint. In order to make fewer than 1 goal, how many goals would she have to make? If you can answer that question, it's just a matter of understanding what the table says.

Comment: would that be .25+.35?

Comment: In order to make **fewer than 1 goal**, how many goals would she have to make?

Comment: You don't count 1, you just take .25?

Comment: Yes, because 1 is not less than 1.